Unexplainable layout error within my code
In my endeavours of making an image editing/face tagging app that can adjust certain components of the image, I continued to encounter errors due to the complexity of the code. As of now in this code, I am attempting to create a tab that is opened from a button in the main software which allows me to edit those said components. However, I seem to be unable to do so due to an error of "QWidget::setLayout: Attempting to set QLayout "" on createwindow "", which already has a layout"
import sys

# sipPyTypeDictRef()
class mainwindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.top=200
        self.left=500
        self.width=700
        self.height=700

        self.imageheight=600
        self.imagewidth=600

        self.setWindowTitle("face tagging")
        
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        # self.buttonname = QPushButton(Title, self)
        #self. buttonname.move(xcoor,ycoor)
        # self.label=QLabel(title, self)
        self.label= QLabel("image presented here ", self)
        
        self.label.move(200,200)
        self.btn2 = QPushButton("image editor", self)
        
        self.btn2.clicked.connect(self.editing_window)
        self.btn3 = QPushButton("button2", self)
        self.btn4 = QPushButton("button3", self)
        vbox = QHBoxLayout()

        vbox.addWidget(self.btn2)
        vbox.addWidget(self.btn3)
        vbox.addWidget(self.btn4)
        self.setLayout(vbox)

        buttons_widget = QWidget()
        buttons_widget.setLayout(vbox)

        hbox= QHBoxLayout()

        hbox.addWidget(self.label)
        hbox.addWidget(buttons_widget)
        self.setLayout(hbox)
        self.setwidget() #removed the argument
    def setwidget(self):
    #self.btn5 = QPushButton("fe pics", self)
    #self.btn6 = QPushButton("fe pics", self)
        self.btn1 = QPushButton("upload here",self)
        self.btn1.clicked.connect(self.obtainphoto)

    
    def editing_window(self): # mainwindow input missing
        self.editwin=createwindow()
        self.editwin.setwidget()#self
        self.editwin.show()

    
    def obtainphoto(self):
        fname= QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "open file")
        self.imagepath= fname[0]
        self.renderimage()
    def renderimage(self):
        self.pixmap = QPixmap(self.imagepath)
        #resized = self.pixmap.scaled(1,1) # fix image display scale if nessacary

        self.pixmap_resized=(self.pixmap.scaled(self.imagewidth,self.imagewidth)) #the .scaled is for increasing size# regular self.pixmap(50,50),(100,100),(200,200)(300,300),(600,600)
        self.label.setPixmap(self.pixmap_resized)
class createwindow(mainwindow):
    def __init__ (self):
        super().__init__()
        self.width=350
        self.height=350
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height) # if i want the new window to be a different size than the original, i will need to write my own parameters under this function. 
    def setwidget(self):
        self.labelwidth= QLabel("width editor",self)
        self.labelwidth.move(900,300)
        self.textwidth=QLineEdit("width",self)  #stopped at pg 20.
        self.textwidth.move(900,350)

        self.labelheight= QLabel("height editor",self)
        self.labelheight.move(1100,300)
        self.textheight=QLineEdit("height",self)
        self.textheight.move(1100,350)  # apply the code which adjusts the positions of the buttons based on the size of the image with this code.
        
        self.labelcolor= QLabel("adjust photo color",self)
        self.labelcolor.move(200,0)

        self.radiobtn1= QRadioButton("original")
        self.radiobtn1.setChecked(True)
        self.radiobtn1.move(200,70)
        self.radiochecked ="original"

        
        self.radiobtn2=QRadioButton("grey",self)
        self.radiobtn2.move(200,15)
        self.radiobtn3=QRadioButton("red",self)
        self.radiobtn3.move(200,30)
        self.radiobtn4=QRadioButton("green",self)
        self.radiobtn4.move(200,50)

        self.radiobtn5= QRadioButton("blue",self)
        self.radiobtn5.move(200,70)


        self.btn_confirm= QPushButton("confirm", self)
        self.btn_confirm.move(300,0)
        self.btn_confirm.clicked.connect(lambda: self.editimage(mainwindow))

        vbox = QVBoxLayout() #originally Vbox
        vbox.addWidget(self.labelwidth)
        vbox.addWidget(self.textwidth)
        vbox.addWidget(self.labelheight)
        vbox.addWidget(self.textheight)
        vbox.addWidget(self.labelcolor)
        vbox.addWidget(self.radiobtn1)
        vbox.addWidget(self.radiobtn2)
        vbox.addWidget(self.radiobtn3)
        vbox.addWidget(self.radiobtn4)
        vbox.addWidget(self.radiobtn5)
        vbox.addWidget(self.btn_confirm)

        # Apply layout
        self.setLayout(vbox)
    def editimage(self, mainwindow):
        imgwidth_edited=self.textwidth.text()
        imgheight_edited=self.textheight.text()

        mainwindow.imagewidth= int(imgwidth_edited)
        mainwindow.imageheight=int(imgheight_edited)
        mainwindow.renderimage()
    
        
if __name__=='__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win=mainwindow()
    

    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
"""
you are able to choose how you format the buttons
QVBoxPlotLayout (vertical layout)
QHBoxPlotLayout (Horizantal Layout)
QGridLayout (Grid layout)

You are able to set a variable equal to any of those following commands

for ex: vbox=QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addwidget(self.btn1) (to all the desired buttons)
        After you have formatted the objects in the desired manner, 
    self.setLayout(vbox)   to officialize the changes.   
"""


The error is self explanatory: the instance of mainwindow already calls setLayout(), and you cannot do that more than once, unless the layout is removed or set as layout of another widget. In fact, you're already doing that twice: the first with vbox, then with hbox, but in that case it's acceptable because you're also calling buttons_widget.setLayout(vbox). Then, when you try to inherit mainwindow for the createwindow subclass, calling its __init__ results in already having a layout set, so you cannot call setLayout() again as you do in setwidget().

Unfortunately, your code is quite messy, and it's really difficult to help you more. For instance, you use lower case names for classes, which makes it hard to distinguish classes and other objects, while classes (and constants) should always use capitalized names (see the official Style Guide for Python Code). This confusion is clear in editimage(), which will try to call mainwindow.renderimage() as it was an instance method, but that will raise an exception because mainwindow is a class.
